# Fixing identation after and if statement Visual Studio 2019 programming in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

After I type `if (view=="") {` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, VS formats and indents the curly braces to this:

```
 if (view == "")
            {

            }
```

How can I change the settings in Visual Studio 2019 to just have it like this

```
  if (view == "")
  {

  }
```

I've been looking and trying different combinations and can't seem to find the setting.

Comment: Your indentation settings may be configured incorrectly? Have a play with them @ Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > Indentation

Comment: is your file part of a project? does your file have a `.cs` extension? do you have any editorconfig files?

Comment: Thats the thing, I have no editorconfig files. This happens only in visual studio 2019.. when i use 2022 i don't have this issue.. Also I had that already unchecked for indentation below didn't work.. This is also a blazor server project. maybe my VS is messed up

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the format you need, you can refer to the parameters of this option:

Tools>Options>Text Editor>C#>Code Style>Formatting>Indentation, uncheck the option ”Indent open and close braces”.

[image]